# Magento Customer model rewrite causing seemingly unrelated JSON parse error

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, magento

Warning, this is not for the faint of heart (sorry for the length)....we have implemented PayPal Transparent Redirect as a custom payment method.  The long and short of it is that We have a custom payment method that takes a credit card and submits it to PayPal without the credit card number ever hitting our server.  It takes the number from the client side, sprinkle some Ajax, JSON and js, and voila(!), you get a credit card approval and the order is submitted in Magento.  The problem is that this works great, except when another custom module that rewrites Mage_Customer is active.  I have narrowed it to one model that I have overwritten.  If I comment out the rewrite node in my config for just that model, the transparent redirect works fine.  I have determined that it is not the code within those models, as I have removed 100% of it.  Just the declaration remains :

```
 <?php


 class Mycompany_Customer_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 {
 }
```

This alone is somehow causing a JSON parse error when the request is sent to PayPal.  Is there something about having a child class as part of the process that could break javascript?  I am not very experienced with JavaScript or JSON, but I do know that the response is coming back, and it looks identical to a success response, yet somehow "OnException" is being triggered. This is the message: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character.

I just don't even see how the two could be related.  Although we have had other strange issues related to model overrides in the past.  For example, I did a rewrite on the Customer Create API to add an additional attribute, and when the incoming XML hits my custom method, it is an object (not an array), so the workaround was to forcibly convert it to an array, however, when it arrives in the standard method, it is an array to start with (I do not need help with this, as it works).

I figure there MUST be an explanation out there for some of these strange issues.  If anyone has any advice on how to troubleshoot this, or any information/experience about why inherited classes can break things, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We haven't completely solved this yet, but we're well on our way.  We're developing on a Windows stack and I manually saved my customer model with UTF-8 encoding.  However, my partner developed all of his PayPal extension and did not save it in UTF-8.  When he converts my model back to ANSI format, his code works, so now he's going to try it the other way around (making his UTF-8) and checking it.  If anybody has advice on encodings and development platforms, I'd like to hear it, still.